# How to fix this? Class was not found

Tags: jquery

I want to add a class to my headline with jQuery, but it didn't work and I have no idea why.

```
$('div#main headline').addClass('main-headline');
```

I already tried to use another element, but that also didn't work.

Comment: There's no `<headline>` element, so I'd presume you're missing a `#` or `.` prefix on that selector. Seeing your HTML would help a lot here.

Comment: That means your selector to find `div#main headline` is not valid. Please fix your selector. Also, it would be great if you can share the HTML snippet of what you are trying to select.

Comment: please add your HTML code too

Comment: typo? `$('div#main headline')` looks like it should be `$('div#main-headline')`?

Answer (score 2):

If **headline** is a class use **.headline** , if id add **#headline** if **headline** is a tag you can check if it exists or not before adding other class.

```
if($(selector).length>0)
{
//your logic here
}
```

if your selector exists it's length is greater than 0 i.e 1 or more

else it doesn't exist